# How to copy files to a network path

Tags: c#

I wnated to copy file form my local drive to network path. I know how this can be achieved by using ssh ftp library i.e using sftp.put(@ local, remote) , but i don't know how do do by using "sudo". What to do in case i don't have write permission to network path.

Although i can remove file from network path by using following code :

```
string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("username");
    string pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");
    string filename;
    filename = "standalone-full.xml";
    string directory1;
    directory1 = "apps/instances/express_13000/configuration";


    // connecting to machine

    SshExec ssh = new SshExec("machine", "user");
    ssh.Password = "password";
    ssh.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Established");

    // removing files from server

    string command_express = "echo" + "'" + pass + "'" + "| sudo -S -u wtsnqa " + "/" + directory1 + "/" + filename + "-exec rm";
    string output1 = ssh.RunCommand(command_express);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx) and [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28VS.71%29.aspx) method.

Also check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx).

Comment: For the sake of future readers (and the possibility of dead links) it would be good to summarize the content of the linked resource.